# TweetSharp error Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, twitter

I am working on an old application that uses TweetSharp to list tweets on the website but recently I started to receive the following error which after hours of trying I am unable to work out why

[image]

I have the following code

```
        //get the twitter username
        TwitterUsername = SpotlightPage.Property["TwitterUsername"].ToString();

        //load tweets from the cache
        var tweets = Context.Cache["TwitterSpotlight" + TwitterUsername] as IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>;

        //If the cache doesn't exist or has expired, get the list of tweets again and set the cache
        if (tweets == null)
        {
            var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);

            //set options for listing tweets
            var options = new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions();

            //set the screen name to be the username
            options.ScreenName = TwitterUsername;

            // The number of tweets to display
            options.Count = 6;

            //Get the list of tweets.
            tweets = service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(options);

            //only if we got tweets add them to the cache
            if (tweets != null)
            {
                    //Cache the output of the tweets
                    Context.Cache.Add("TwitterSpotlight" + TwitterUsername, tweets, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
        }

        tweetdisplay.DataSource = tweets;
        tweetdisplay.DataBind();
```

If i set the count of tweets to > 5 then i will recieve the JSON error descried in the image above. This would suggest that there may be an issue with the data in the 6th tweet but i cant see anything that may cause an issue. I have read other posts that suggest emojis/smileys can cause this kind of behaviour and the dirty fix is to delete the tweet. I simply cant delete tweets and need to ensure this is stable.

I am wondering if anyone has resolved this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you deserialize ? and show this json with problems?

Comment: I don't have access to that code sorry, how can it work and then not work is what I don't understand

Comment: @Paul Getting the same errors with Emojis..did you ever manage to fix this?

Comment: @randommman - We never had time to resolve the issue sorry so we just excluded retweets from being displayed and if an emoji was used in a tweet then we caught the error as opposed to the YSOD. Good Luck